# Mud tubes on outside of house:What to do?

Tags: pest-control, insect

There are 3 mud tubes on the outside of a basement window, under a deck. They are not connected to the ground.  What might I do about them? See photos.
enter image description here

[image]
[image]

Comment: don't do anything about those ... you are lucky to have them ... they are beneficial insects that get rid of pests in your garden ... the mud tubes contain only the larva of a solitary bee, not the adults

Answer (score 3):

**These are old wasp nests**.

[image: wasp nests]

https://www.colonialpest.com/dont-confuse-mud-dauber-tubes-termite-tubes/

These are mud dauber nests.  They are harmless.  The wasps are awesome creatures.  Marvel at their works!

I  will try to knock down the nests of paper wasps around inhabited areas because they get so big and there are so many wasps.  But the mud daubers never get that populous.  I leave those nests alone.

Comment: Wasps are harmless to humans but beneficial to our goals of living pest-free. They sting when they have to for a defense, but generally are an asset to have around a yard.

Answer (score 0):

Spray them with the narrow, forceful setting on your hose nozzle and keep spraying until they disintegrate. Wipe the area down with a course cloth but be careful not to scratch the surface. A little dish washing soap will help to clean the surface.

Comment: Are they likely to reappear?

Comment: FYI, when I hit the tubes with a strong stream of water, some parts washed away immediately, some parts washed away after a minute or so, and other parts resisted the water for several minutes, without obvious change.  Then I tried to dislodge the remaining tubes with a stick. Some parts of the mud tunnels were really hard, even after being hosed down for 5 minutes.  I rubbed most of the mud away, but some stubborn parts are still stuck to the frame of the window. I'll monitor the area. (Good idea.)

Comment: @JACK you should really examine your place in nature before you destroy and poison creatures that do you no harm

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC  That depends on how old they are. If they do re appear, check with the locals to determine if they're the good bugs that help get rid of insects.

Comment: @jsotola  You're absolutely right... I was thinking about South Florida  where most of what flies either stings, bites or eats your house.

Comment: @JACK that actually makes good sense ... self preservation has to come first

Comment: I couldn't imagine living peacefully with any indoor pest. If they are good to the environment or yard, that's where they shall inhibit, not with me, and can be seen.